# String blank (empty or null) check : if structure vs java 8 optional/filter

Tags: java, java-8

**Question**:
Which approach is better and why

1- Using Apache Commons

```
if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(str) {
     list.add(str)
}
```

2- Optional & filter

```
Optional.ofNullable(str)
                .filter(s -> StringUtils.isNotBlank(s))
                .ifPresent(result -> list.add(result));
```

Comment: Could you please clarify where you take those strings?

Comment: Your context just says "If a string is not null". The way to check that is `if (str!=null)`. The alternatives in your question do something different.

Comment: I meant to say null or empty.

Comment: 1st one is pretty and simple but using optional here create bunch of code under the hood

Comment: Then I would use `if (str!=null && !str.isEmpty())`. But definitely not the one with the Optional.

Comment: Note: questions asking to *review* **working** code to suggest improvements ... might rather go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ... also note: "is better" always depends on context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Question**: Which approach is better and why

**The first one**, because in the second one you create an **unnecessary** `Optional`

---

But I would suggest to use [`isNotEmpty`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotEmpty-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead of `isNotBlank`:

```
if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(str)){
   list.add(str)
}
```

To know the difference between [`isNotEmpty`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotEmpty-java.lang.CharSequence-) and [`isNotBlank`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNotBlank-java.lang.CharSequence-) in doc:

> Checks if a CharSequence is **not empty** ("") and **not null**.

> Checks if a CharSequence is **not empty** (""), **not null** and **not whitespace only**.

In your case you ask null or empty, where `isNotEmpty` is the correct one for your case.

Answer (score 1):

More of an addendum: my vote went almost immediately to your first option.

Why? Simply: simplicity!

The second snippet is nothing but an if-statement in disguise. And that disguise comes with plenty of overhead.

Your human readers have to look at all the characters, then they need to dissect the complex statement, then they need to **know** how Optional works, and what the given code **actually** does.

So, besides the subtle performance differences, as outlined in the other answer: the real answer: you should ask the people in your team.

If they are all used to `Optional` usage like here, and they do that all day long, then, maybe, the **better** style is option 2. Because that is what all of you do, day in day out. But if not, as said: I recommend to go with the simpler lines of code, that can be understood by anybody who knows basic java.